# Threading when reading a large txt file in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to read several very large txt files and have to either use multiple threads or a single thread to do so depending on user input.

Say I have a main method that gets user input, and the user requests a single thread and wants to process 20 txt files for that thread.  How would I accomplish this? Note that the code below isn't my code or its setup, but just what the "idea" is.

Example:

```
int numFiles = 20;
int threads = 1;

 String[] list = new String[20];
 for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++){
   list[i] = "hello" + i + ".txt";//so the list is a hello1.txt, hello2.txt, ...,  hello20.txt
 }

 public void run(){
 //processes txt file
 }
```

So in summary, how would I accomplish this with a single thread? With 20 threads?

Comment: Can you tag your question with the language you are using (Java I think)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a configurable pool of threads, and each file-read operation is a job to be submitted into that pool.

When the user specifies how many threads to use, you'd configure the pool appropriately, submit the set of file-read jobs, and let the pool sort out the executions.

In the Java world, you'd use the [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) factory method, and submit each job as a [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). [Here's an article from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html) on Java thread pooling.

Comment: And the project specifies that we must do this with either a single thread or the number of threads equal to the number of text files, so a case with 20 files that need processing with one thread is a case.

Comment: Actually, it is quite possible that you will SLOW DOWN the application if you try to use multiple threads to read different parts of a file.  Standard magnetic disk hardware (and the OS) are optimized for reading files sequentially, not in parallel.  Think "disk head movement" ...